# Colocar texto detrás de imágenes mientras cargan

Tags: html, imagen

He creado la web de mi empresa en base a una plantilla y he notado un pequeño inconveniente. Las imágenes tardan en cargar aún cuando pesan 20-30 kb.
Es que las galerías contienen y contendrán muchas imágenes, dado que es la idea mostrar mi trabajo.

Quisiera colocar un texto de fondo "cargando" o un gif mientras las imágenes no aparecen. No se si es viable, pero dejo aquí el link de una de las páginas de mi web para puedan ver de qué se trata y a qué me refiero:
http://imprimas.com.uy/invitaciones.html

Verán que después del banner y un breve texto, el sitio queda "vacío" hasta cargarse las imágenes todas de una vez.

Gracias por la ayuda, es mi primer pregunta! :D
Saludos,
Santiago.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es bien recibida porque necesitas subir el codigo de lo que has intentado. En mi caso no puedo entrar a tu web porque estoy restringido en el trabajo. Asi que mejor trata de subir en [Ejemplo minimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Ademas debes indicar que tecnolgias estas usando.

Comment: Debes especificar con etiquetas las tecnologías que estás usando para poderte dar una solución basada en esto. Puedes hacerlo dándole al botón editar en la pregunta y debajo de la misma colocar las etiquetas

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Santiago, considera leer [ask] para que realices correctamente una pregunta, esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente debes especificar el atributo `alt` en las imagenes

Por ejemplo

```html
<img src="imagen.jpg" alt="Titulo de la imagen o texto mientras se carga o si falla la carga">
```

El atributo `alt` basicamente especifica un texto alternativo para una imagen, si la imagen no se puede mostrar.

Answer (score 0):

Mil disculpas por mi desconocimiento en el funcionamiento del foro.

No soy programador, por eso me cuesta mucho pero intentaré copiar el código.
Es que también incluye archivos .js, son varios y no logro notar al 100% cuál de ellos corre para realizar el efecto de las imágenes.

Lo que tengo en html es esto

```
 <article class="style1">
 <span class="image">
 <img src="images/souvenirs/souv54.jpg" alt="Cargando..." />
 </span>
 </article>
```

En este caso el atributo ALT no es lo que busco dado que aparecería solo si la imagen no se puede mostrar. En mi caso, la imagen se muestra, pero tarda mucho en cargar porque son varias (unas 60). En esa espera, no aparece nada y temo que los invitados a mi sitio entiendan como que no existe tal galería de fotos.
De ser posible, me gustaría que ingresaran al sitio para entender mejor mi problema en cuestión.

Muchas gracias!